# Bounds checking for the center of a UIView while dragging it around

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview, drag-and-drop

I have `UIView` elements that i want to drag around the screen. But i want that no-matter what, their center should be always inside the bounds of their superview.
I added to them an UIPanGestureRecognizer and i making the bounds checking as follows:

```
-(void) dragInProgress : (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
    if ([self.delegate hallElement:self shouldMove:recognizer])
    {
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view.superview];

        CGPoint currentCenter = self.view.center;

        CGFloat maxX = self.view.superview.bounds.size.width;
        if (currentCenter.x + translation.x < 0 )
        {
            translation.x =  (0 - currentCenter.x);
        }
        if (currentCenter.x + translation.x >= maxX ) 
        {  
            translation.x = (maxX - currentCenter.x - 1);
        }

        CGFloat maxY = self.view.superview.bounds.size.height;
        if (currentCenter.y  + translation.y < 0 )    
        {  
            translation.y = (0 - currentCenter.y);
        }
        if (currentCenter.y + translation.y >= maxY ) 
        {  
            translation.y = (maxY - currentCenter.y - 1);
        }

        [recognizer setTranslation:translation inView:self.view.superview];
        CGPoint translationInViewCoordiateSystem = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.view.transform, translationInViewCoordiateSystem.x  ,  translationInViewCoordiateSystem.y  );
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
    }
}
```

But this bound checking is not working at the best case, and usually results in weird behavior. 
How can i ensure that the center will remain within the bounds of the superview?

Comment: Define "weird behaviour" please. You've told us what you want to see, but what are you seeing? Your logic looks ok to me.

Comment: What comes after the code you posted? In what context does the posted code exist? What method is it in?

Comment: @occulus: Weird behavior is that sometimes the bound checking only letting me move the view in a certain direction although i'm in the center of the screen and not even close to the edges.

This code is inside the handler of the UIPanGestureRecognizer.
At the end of the method, after all the calculations are done, i'm translating the transform of my view with the calculated translation, and then reseting the translation back to zero.

Comment: Please show the code for "At the end of the method, after all the calculations are done, i'm translating the transform of my view with the calculated translation, and then reseting the translation back to zero."

Comment: I edited the post and included all the method. 
Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem:
The transform translation is not changing the center of the view, so the bounds checking for the center is never really efficient because the center always stay the same even though the view is actually traveling across the screen.

So the solution will be to replace the following lines:

```
[recognizer setTranslation:translation inView:self.view.superview];
        CGPoint translationInViewCoordiateSystem = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.view.transform, translationInViewCoordiateSystem.x  ,  translationInViewCoordiateSystem.y  );
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
```

With:

```
currentCenter.x += translation.x;
currentCenter.y += translation.y;
self.view.center = currentCenter;
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view.superview];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your centre isn't always going to be within the actual bounds -- it can go over by 1 pixel in the maximum X and Y directions. Not sure if that's causing your problem, but this code should fix that bounds issue:

```
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view.superview];
CGPoint currentCenter = self.view.center;

CGFloat maxX = self.view.superview.bounds.size.width;
if (currentCenter.x + translation.x < 0 )
{
    translation.x =  (0 - currentCenter.x);
}

if (currentCenter.x + translation.x >= maxX ) // A CHANGE HERE
{  
    translation.x = (maxX - currentCenter.x - 1);  // A CHANGE HERE
}

CGFloat maxY = self.view.superview.bounds.size.height;
if (currentCenter.y  + translation.y < 0 )    
{  
    translation.y = (0 - currentCenter.y);
}

if (currentCenter.y + translation.y >= maxY ) // A CHANGE HERE
{  
    translation.y = (maxY - currentCenter.y - 1); // A CHANGE HERE
}
```